# Change individual numbers color in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this function in React to change the buttons' color. But it changes all buttons and not just an individual one. How can I do that?

```
  function changeButtonColor() {
    setNumbersColor(numbersColor === 'green' ? 'red' : 'green');
  }

  const [numbersColor, setNumbersColor] = useState('green');
  return (
        <NumbersContainer>
          {numbersList.map((num) => (
            <Numbers
              key={num}
              style={{ backgroundColor: numbersColor }}
              onClick={changeButtonColor}
            >
              {formatNumber(num)}
            </Numbers>
          ))}
        </NumbersContainer>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the numbers component by it self, and make it responsible for it's own colors

```
import React from "react"

const Button = (props) => {
  const [numbersColor, setNumbersColor] = useState("green")
  
  const changeButtonColor = ()=>{
    setNumbersColor(numbersColor === 'green' ? 'red' : 'green')
  }

  return(
    <button
       style={{ backgroundColor: numbersColor }}
       onClick={changeButtonColor}
     >
     {props.children}
     </button>

  )
}

const NumbersList = () => {
    return (
        <NumbersContainer>
          {numbersList.map((num) => (
            <Button key={num}>
              {formatNumber(num)}
            </Button>
          ))}
        </NumbersContainer>
    )
}
```